# Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Now that I'm over on Android Studio (1.1.0) I'm am unable to use the emulator.  My app runs fine on actual devices.

All of the answers to this problem I find on this forum and other sources say to just let it the emulator run until the lock screen appears but I don't think I will live long enough to try that solution.

When I used Eclipse I could just hit run and it would start up the emulator and everything would run.  That didn't work in AS.  Next I start up the AVD separately and I get the dark screen with the word android( in the weird font) with the light flashing across  the word.  I let it set there for up to a half an hour and nothing happens.  If I then run the module, I get the error in the title of this post.

This is my AVD definition: (I have changed everything I can think of and nothing seems to make a difference.
For a better picture [look here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39662979/ASEmu.png)
[image: AVD def]
This is my gradle.buile for the module . . .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:15'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.deanblakely.mttTrial"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87')
    {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
}
```

Comment: try restarting the adb

Comment: adb connect localhost

Comment: none of that has any effect.